# Android manifest activity name generates a RunTime exception

Tags: android-activity, xamarin.forms, android-manifest

Trying to name an `activity` in my Android.manifest file following the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element):

```xml
<manifest 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0"
  package="com.companyname.xamarinauth"
>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="XamarinAuth.Android" >

      <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="obsolete-scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

    </application>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

No matter what class name or string I provide to the activity's name property I get a run time exception:

```
**Java.Lang.RuntimeException:** 'Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.companyname.xamarinauth/com.companyname.xamarinauth.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.companyname.xamarinauth.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.xamarinauth-LAUvw_T2YXTzpe7rXmRWhg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.xamarinauth-LAUvw_T2YXTzpe7rXmRWhg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.companyname.xamarinauth-LAUvw_T2YXTzpe7rXmRWhg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
```

The boilerplate Xamarin code generated by Visual Studio creates the MainActivity class for me:

```cs
    [Activity(
        Label = "XamarinAuth",
        Icon = "@mipmap/icon",
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
        MainLauncher = true, 
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation
        )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{...}
```

I am assuming `FormsAppCompatActivity` is a subclass of `Activity`? Providing a name of any variation on the theme of `com.companyname.xamarinauth.MainActivity` generates the error. What am I missing?

Comment: According to the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/krruzic/16d391bcbcc103df9eb86bf103784d6d) I added the `Name` property to the  MainActivity class annotation and got by the error. Is the the "answer"?

Comment: If you create Activity and use the [Activity] custom attribute, you will see Activity name in bj/Debug/android/AndroidManifest.xml. More detailed info, you can see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT great link - thank you! This really is the answer - please re-post and I will check it off.

Comment: I have post, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create Activity and use the [Activity] custom attribute, you will see Activity name in bj/Debug/android/AndroidManifest.xml.

*AndroidManifest.xml is generated as part of the build process, and the XML found within Properties/AndroidManifest.xml is merged with XML that is generated from custom attributes. The resulting merged AndroidManifest.xml resides in the obj subdirectory; for example, it resides at obj/Debug/android/AndroidManifest.xml for Debug builds. The merging process is trivial: it uses custom attributes within the code to generate XML elements, and inserts those elements into AndroidManifest.xml.*

More detailed info, please take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest